# detecting DTMF digits from mat file

Tags: matlab

I am trying to decode numbers in a matfile given and was hoping if someone could help me figure out how to figure out the number. Using fft command is a requirement.

I used fft(number) and decided to plot using stem(abs(number)) however i am not figuring out how to figure out what digit is being pressed, was hoping if someone could explain or tell me if i am using the wrong commands

Comment: i need to use fft command and learn how to figure out how to get digit from results when other question just wants to split duplicate, plus the

Comment: Look at the  `fft` examples in MATLAB to see how you can plot the output of `fft` in terms of amplitude against frequency. You need to know the sampling frequency of the signal. That will give you a start.